# How do you refer to the act of a delegate resigning?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

When a president resigns, they might entitle their resignation letter "Resignation from Presidency."  A councilor might entitle their letter "Resignation from Council."  What would a delegate entitle their resignation letter?

Here are some contenders that I encountered on google:

- "Resignation as Delegate"
- "Resignation from Delegacy"
- "Resignation of Delegacy"

Is one of these (or a different version) more correct than another?  If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are looking for a parallel term, the natural choice is

> Resignation from delegation

because, just as a *council* is a body of *councilors*, a *delegation* is a body of *delegates*.

See: http://www.google.com/search?q=define+delegation

Comment: Interestingly, according to the google definition, delegation and delegacy are synonyms.  Delegation seems more common than delegacy, so I'm inclined to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Delegacy is the position.  Delegate is the person.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/delegacy?s=t

Style choices abound, but I would go with something like 'resigned her delegacy'.  That said, 'she resigned as delegate' is equally correct.  I would use surrounding text to choose the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Since one normally resigns from an office, I would consider using that word in the title.

> Resignation from delegated office of ...